# Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to use hyperref in my tex  file.. here is a minimal working example.. which gives me the option clash error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     citecolor=black,
     filecolor=black,
     urlcolor=black,
 } 
\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Everything was working fine earlier, but I had to reinstall my  Ubuntu and now when I compile I get the error `Option clash for package hyperref`
I am NOT explicitly calling hyperref twice. I only want to call it once. The thing is I had fixed the problem many months back, and now I just do not remember how I did it :( and this is driving me crazy.

UPDATE:

This is my precise output from command line pdflatex.exe with the above MWE. I get the same error for the MWE. The line 102 mentioned below is from hyperref.sty .. i found out by grepping in the folder.. what does that mean?

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.102 \usepackage
                 [numbered]{hypdoc}
? H
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [colorlinks,hyperindex=false,pdfusetitle,pdfpagelabels]
Adding the global options:
  ,colorlinks,hyperindex=false,pdfusetitle,pdfpagelabels
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the code you show loads hyperref once, so the code you don't show is also loading it once, I don't know what help we can give other than that given no information in the question.

Comment: also if you type `h` to the error prompt it describes how to avoid the error.

Comment: @jarauh I have added the MWE .. thank you for your response

Comment: Hmmm... If I copy your MWE to a file and run `pdflatex` on it, I don't get any error.

Comment: yeah the same code used to work.. i use TexStudio not the command line.. let me try the command line.. what arguments did you give to pdflatex

Comment: @jarauh  please check the question again i updated it with output from terminal.. thank you!!

Comment: @physicist the code you posted is only 15 lines long (and doesn't load `hypcap`). How can it possibly lead to the error you posted where the error is in line 102 (where `hypcap` is loaded)? Would you have built a real minimal example as is described in the link jarauh gave you your MWE would have been `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\begin{document}
\end{document}` and we could have told you immediatley the solution: switch the order of `hyperref` and `hypcap`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}`

Comment: @clemens thanks the problem is fixed. the line 102 was from a.sty file used during compilation

Comment: I have the same problem and I found that it was due to some collision with the hyperref package. Are there any alternative packages? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have an outdated system or you have an local tree, which containes an outdated package `hyperref`, calling `hypdoc` as you can see in the error message, you cited.

With the current MiKTeX, version `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.19)` I added a command `\listfiles` (before `\documentclass{}`) to get a ist of used packages and versions on my system.  You will found this list at the end of your `.log` file:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   color.sty    2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Please compare with you system. I guess you will find some differences ...

Comment: you are genius may I say, I figured out there was a stray hyperref.sty file in my directory. As you say it was old, and i just deleted it and it worked. Perils of having a cluttered directory. I saw your answer after fixing and you are bang ON. thank you :)

Comment: Now I feel like a idiot for asking this question lol..

Comment: @physicist there is no need to feel like an idiot. To recognize such errors is not easy! And your qusetion can help other users having the same problem!